# Trap process crash which occurs in handle_call

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I have 2 GenServer modules - A and B. B monitors A and implements `handle_info` to receive `:DOWN` message when A crashes.

In my example code, B makes synchronous request (`handle_call`) to A. While processing the request, A crashes. B is supposed to receive `:DOWN` message but it doesn't. Why?

When I replaced `handle_call` with `handle_cast`, B received `:DOWN` message. Can you please tell me why `handle_call` doesn't work whereas `handle_cast` does?

This is the simple example code:

```
defmodule A do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :A)
  end

  def fun(fun_loving_person) do
    GenServer.call(fun_loving_person, :have_fun)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_call(:have_fun, _from, state) do
    ######################### Raise an error to kill process :A
    raise "TooMuchFun"

    {:reply, :ok, state}
  end
end

defmodule B do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :B)
  end

  def spread_fun(fun_seeker) do
    GenServer.call(:B, {:spread_fun, fun_seeker})
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_call({:spread_fun, fun_seeker}, _from, state) do
    ######################### Monitor :A
    Process.monitor(Process.whereis(:A))

    result = A.fun(fun_seeker)
    {:reply, result, state}
  rescue
    _ -> IO.puts "Too much fun rescued"
    {:reply, :error, state}
  end

  ######################### Receive :DOWN message because I monitor :A
  def handle_info({:DOWN, _ref, :process, _pid, _reason}, state) do
    IO.puts "============== DOWN DOWN DOWN =============="
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end

try do
  {:ok, a} = A.start_link
  {:ok, _b} = B.start_link
  :ok = B.spread_fun(a)
rescue
  exception -> IO.puts "============= #{inspect exception, pretty: true}"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my example code, B makes synchronous request (handle_call) to A. While processing the request, A crashes. B is supposed to receive :DOWN message but it doesn't. Why?

B does receive the `:DOWN` message when A crashes, but because you are still in the handler for the call to A, it won't have an opportunity to handle the `:DOWN` message until the `handle_call` callback completes. It won't ever complete though, because the call will fail with an exit, which will crash B as well.

> When I replaced handle_call with handle_cast, B received :DOWN message. Can you please tell me why handle_call doesn't work whereas handle_cast does?

Calls are synchronous, casts are asynchronous, so in this case, the `handle_call` callback which casts to A completes, and B is then free to handle the `:DOWN` message. B doesn't crash because casts implicitly ignore any failure in attempting to send the message, it's "fire and forget".

It seems to me you are trying to deal with A crashing when calling to it, that is trivially done like so:

```
def handle_call({:spread_fun, fun_seeker}, _from, state) do
  ######################### Monitor :A
  Process.monitor(Process.whereis(:A))

  result = A.fun(fun_seeker)
  {:reply, result, state}
catch
  :exit, reason ->
    {:reply, {:error, reason}, state}
rescue
  _ -> 
   IO.puts "Too much fun rescued"
   {:reply, :error, state}
end
```

This will catch the exit which occurs when the remote process is not alive, dies, or times out. You can match on specific exit reasons, such as `:noproc` by specifying the reason in the `catch` clause which you want to protect against.

It's not clear to me that you need the monitor, I guess it depends on what you want to use it for, but in your given example I would say you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! Awesome explanation.
I have a RabbitMQ message consumer (module B) that depends on another module (A). I don't want messages to be in limbo when A crashes and B can't reject and requeue the message. Do you know of any better approach?

Comment: Well one approach is to have B drop the message if A fails, and let the message expire and be requeued by RabbitMQ automatically (assuming your queues are appropriately configured). Another is to use the `catch` tactic above, and retry the message a few times before giving up. Yet another is to have B hand the message off to a process which is responsible for handling that message, freeing B up to continue consuming other messages and have that process retry until it succeeds; but that only works if the order of the messages is unimportant, and then you have a flow control problem to deal with

Comment: In my opinion, your better off either finding a way to let B reject/requeue messages (which should certainly be doable if you are catching exits), or dropping failed messages and letting them expire and requeue automatically. It really depends on what guarantees you need to provide though, retry may be a better choice if the order of the messages is critical.